# Unable to lookup WebSphere JNDI java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBImpl cannot be cast to com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB

Tags: spring, websphere, ibm-mq, jndi

I am trying to lookup WebSphere JNDI through spring. The Spring configuration configuration is provided below:

```
<bean id="WebSphereNamingServiceInfo"
        class="com.NamingServiceInfo">
    <property name="providerUrl" value="corbaloc:iiop:infxlmps5d.apac.nsroot.net:9876" />
    <property name="contextFactory"
            value="com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory" />
</bean>
```

The list of the Jars that are used is provided below:

- com.ibm.jaxws.thinclient-8.5.0.jar
- com.ibm.mq.commonservices-7.5.0.jar
- com.ibm.mq.headers-7.5.0.6.jar
- com.ibm.mq.jmqi-7.5.0.6.jar
- com.ibm.mq-7.5.0.jar
- com.ibm.mqetclient-7.0.1.1.jar
- com.ibm.mqjms-7.5.0.6.jar
- com.ibm.ws.runtime_8.5.0-8.5.0.jar
- ibmorb.jar

  Exception observed is:

  Could Not Create A Connection To corbaloc::infxlmps5d.apac.nsroot.net:9876 Using Naming Service (NamingServiceInfo(ProviderURL:corbaloc:iiop:infxlmps5d.apac.nsroot.net:9876)(ContextFactory:com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory)(Login:null))

  Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to initialize the ORB [Root exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]
      at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.getOrb(Helpers.java:400)

  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)

  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBImpl cannot be cast to com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB
      at com.ibm.ws.orb.GlobalORBFactory.init(GlobalORBFactory.java:92)

Please help thanks in advance.

Comment: configuration in spring file
<bean id="WebSphereNamingServiceInfo"
  class="com.NamingServiceInfo">
 <property name="providerUrl" value="corbaloc:iiop:infxlmps5d.apac.nsroot.net:9876" />
 <property name="contextFactory"
   value="com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory" />
</bean>

Comment: Are you deploying java web app in Websphere app server? Or are you connecting your app to JNDI hosted on remote Websphere instance?